# Decomposition time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, seasonality, trend, decomposition

I am studying a daily dataset from a game which contains informations about the peak of players from 2013-2023. This is my first try applying decomposition to see how time series components behaves. Later I would like to perform a forecasting using some models, I have applied the ADF test and it revealed the series as stationary. I'm having some questions to determine what value could fit better in the period parammeter with a daily data.

This is the series over the whole time
[image: Period observed (2013-2023)]
I've used the statsmodels seasonal_decompose() with a period value as **365** and this is the results obtained using additive and multiplicative model.

Additive model:
[image: Additive model]

Multiplicative model:
[image: Multiplicative model]

Based on different types of time series data such as annual, monthly and daily, how should the choice of period be made?

Comment: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/